# ASP equivalent of Ajax?

Tags: asp.net, database, asp-classic

Weird question. I need to use a JavaScript array with ID's in it, to fetch additional information from a database, using the ID's as the row ID.

I need to then use this additional information and send it to another file (aspx) using Ajax, which will then use this information to rotate images.

Unless I can use ASP Classic, and ASP.NET (C#) in the same file? 
- Or can I use the more or less same ASP code to access my database?

rotate script

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" Debug="true" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Drawing" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Web" %>

<script runat="server">
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //string url = Request.QueryString["url"];
    string url = @"C:\inetpub\wwwroot\testing\image.jpg";
    string rotate_dir = Request.QueryString["dir"];

    //create an image object from the image in that path
    System.Drawing.Image img = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(url);

    //Rotate the image in memory
    if (rotate_dir == "clockwise")
    {
        //Rotate clockwise
        img.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate90FlipNone);
    } else if (rotate_dir == "anticlockwise")
    {
        //Rotate anti-clockwise
        img.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate90FlipXY);
    }

    //Delete the file so the new image can be saved
    System.IO.File.Delete(url);

    //save the image to the file
    img.Save(url);

    //release image file
    img.Dispose();
}
</script>
```

What I use to access my database

```
'Create connection and load users database
set conn=Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
conn.Provider="Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0"
conn.Open Server.MapPath("/nightclub_photography/data/database/jamsnaps.mdb")
```

Hope you understand what I'm trying to do?

Comment: Sorry, no, it does not make sense to me. I see you rotate the image, what does Asp Classic have to do with this? what is the Database for?

Comment: @HanletEscaño I think he didn't get that Asp.NET also supports database connections to ACCESS or older formats, and thinks he must use asp-classic for datafetching :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you should know you can freely use Javascript (and thus ajax) in asp-classic.

this means you can easily do the following;

```
set conn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
set rs = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
conn.open Server.MapPath("foobar path") + ", Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0"
%><script type="text/javascript">
rotationArray = Array(id_Array.length);
for(int i = 0; i < id_Array.Length; i++
{
  <% rs.open("SELECT rotation FROM images WHERE id="+ id_Array[i])%>
  rotationArray[i] = <%= rs("rotation") %>;
  <%rs.close() %>
}

//send rotationArray via ajax
```

but in general I would suggest you use Database tools for asp.NET instead.
then you just send your JS-IDArray to the aspx file and do the processing there.

for reference you can check [here](http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/aspnet_dbconnection.asp)

Answer (score 1):

You can use C#.Net and ASP together. Its not a very nice way to do it. My understanding is you have to create the C#project first then add any asp pages. This will allow you to call your C# pages from within the asp application.

I havent personally done one of these but I have seen it done for sure so I know its technically possible.

Comment: i know it is possible... but it's not really worth the effort. in our company we do this as an interim solution as we migrate Intranet to c#